# Showing by definition that a curve is a 1 dimensional differentiable manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

> Let $\gamma :(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $C^1$ curve and $S = \left \{ x  |  \exists t\in(a,b) : \gamma(t)=x  \right \}$ its image.
>
> Show that if $\gamma$ is injective and $\gamma' (t) \neq \vec{0}, \forall t \in (a,b)$, then $S$ is a one dimensional differentiable manifold in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Just to clarify the definition we were taught: I need to show that $\forall x \in S$, there exists an open neighborhood $V \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ of $x$ s.t $S \cap V$ is the graph of a differentiable function $f: U \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{d-1}$.

I believe this should be a pretty basic exercise but I'm a little lost. Help appreciated.

*EDIT: The above question is false as mentioned, modifying the question this way:

> Let $\gamma :(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $C^1$ curve and $S = \left \{ x  |  \exists t\in(a+\varepsilon ,b-\varepsilon) : \gamma(t)=x  \right \}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$, the image of $\gamma |_{(a+\varepsilon ,b-\varepsilon)}$.
>
> Show that if $\gamma$ is injective and $\gamma' (t) \neq \vec{0}, \forall t \in (a,b)$, then $S$ is a one dimensional differentiable manifold in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

how would we prove it?

Comment: This statement is false. For a discussion and a depiction of a counterexample, see the (somewhat poorly written) entry on wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Immersed_submanifolds

Comment: There's a typo in the problem. The assumption should be $\gamma'(t)\ne 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for noticing, my bad

Comment: It's still false for the reason Lee Mosher has pointed out, though.

Comment: Yes, @Lee's reference to what I presume is the figure-eight is still a counterexample. You will need to add *proper* to make the problem correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Doesn't being injective mean it's proper?

Comment: Absolutely not, @paxtibimarce. The definition of proper is that $\gamma^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact $K\subset\Bbb R^d$.

Comment: Compactness is crucially a part of analysis. But here's the other way: You need to know that $\gamma^{-1}$  is continuous (as a map with domain $\gamma((a,b))$, of course). The point is that you'll need to know that each point of the image has a neighborhood in $\Bbb R^d$ that is just diffeomorphic to an interval in $\Bbb R$. Then you can apply the inverse/implicit function theorem. But yes, I think your instructor messed up.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for all the help, I have fixed the question, If you would like to take a look perhaps.

Comment: @LeeMosher what if $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ are explicitly not contained in the curve? I.e. the limit points at the two ends do not intersect the middle of the curve?

Comment: I doubt that your "graph definition" makes sense. The graph of $f : U \to \mathbb R^{d-1}$ is the set $\{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in U \} \subset \mathbb R^d$. But then $\{0\} \times \mathbb R$ would not be a one- dimensional differentiable manifold in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Paul Frost I don't see the problem, you just take the function which is identically zero in that case which is differentiable. (Notice we can choose which coordinates our function works on).

Comment: @paxtibimarce Then you get the $x$-axis as a graph. Or do you have an alternative definition of the graph of a function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this definition is for a differentiable manifold. It would be great if you could explain in more detail where is the problem.

Comment: @paxtibimarce Your  definition is that $S \subset \mathbb R^d$ is a $k$-dimensional manifold if it is locally the graph of some $f : U \to \mathbb R^{d-k}$ with $U \subset \mathbb R^k$ open. You use it only for $k=1$, but this is irrelevant. So what is the precise definition of the graph? If you agree that it is the set $G(f) = \{(x,f(x)) \in \mathbb R^d \mid x \in U\}$, then the  $y$-axis in $\mathbb R^2$ is not a $1$-manifold (which may be intended?) because in a graph we only have one point with a given $x$-coordinate. Alternatively you need a more general definition of what a graph is.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: we'll assume the function $\gamma$ proper, in order to avoid pathological cases (i.e. the curve getting infinitely close to itself - though without self-intersections). I thank Ted Shifrin for his observations and corrections on this proof.

I'll use the notation $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),...,\gamma_d(t))$.

For a fixed $t_0$ you can take one of the $d$ axis, say $\hat{x_1}$ (if not, $\hat{x_2}$...) such that $\gamma '(t_0)$ is not perpendicular to $\hat{x_1}$.

Then $\gamma_1'(t_0)\neq 0$ and I can take an interval on $\hat{x_1}$ where it remains $\neq0$. Over this interval, I reparametrise $Im\gamma$ as:

$\alpha(s)=(\gamma \circ \gamma_1^{-1})(s) = (\gamma_1 \circ \gamma_1^{-1},\gamma_2 \circ \gamma_1^{-1},...,\gamma_d \circ \gamma_1^{-1})(s) = (s, \alpha_2(s),...,\alpha_d(s)) $

by using that $\gamma_1' \neq 0 \Rightarrow \gamma_1$ bijective.

And there we have a local graph (if we restrict on $V\cap S$ with $V\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ a suitable open set)

Comment: For the second line, I can't have that $\gamma'(t_0)$ is perpendicular to every axis. If it was, then $||\gamma'(t_0)||^2=(\gamma'(t_0)\cdot \hat{x_1})^2+...+ (\gamma'(t_0)\cdot \hat{x_d})^2=0$

Comment: Right. The question then is why shrinking to $S$ solves the problem that the proof would otherwise be wrong.

Comment: Well, I skipped that because since I restrict $\gamma_1$, I should also restrict $\alpha$ and therefore $Im\alpha$

Comment: But why does that solve the problem? You need an open set in $\Bbb R^d$ whose intersection with the curve is *only* your graph.

Comment: You mean I should copy & paste the first two points of my other answer? I guess so.

Comment: No, that isn’t sufficient. Far-away points of the curve can approach your point ... or could before $S$ was introduced.

Comment: Well I honestly thought that $\varepsilon$ had to be determined afterwards and the question was badly written.

Comment: Think about the figure 8 example that we referred to in the original comments.